# Expl3 token list with UTF-8 characters (or seeing it as a byte list)

Tags: expl3, latex3

I'm currently using `expl3` code in a project. It's been a slow learning process.

Now I need to deal with an UTF-8 input stream, but, as I already suspected there's a problem dealing with 2-byte encodings.

Actually, if the input is UTF-8 or not is not relevant for my case. I want to process, for example `até` and have the following outcome: `a`, `t`, `0xC3` and `0xA9`. In other words, processing it one byte at a time. In LaTex, I want to have something like `\processtl{até}`  and have `at{0xC3}{0xA9}` as the 4-token tl.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\processtl}[1]{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tokens_tl { #1 }
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tokens_tl { (##1) } %% Here: check one byte!
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
token list: \processtl{abc{$\beta$}}\par
% token list with á and ç: \processtl{ábç{$\beta$}}\par  % FAILS
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to recognize the `0xC3` and treat it separately from the following byte?

Something like:

```
\IfTestByte{#1=0xC3){                  % check if current byte is the first UTF-8
    \showinhexadecimal(0xC3}           % output it in hex
    \getnexttoken                      % get the second byte
    \showinhexadecimal{\thenexttoken}  % output it in hex
}
```

I can't convert `tl` to `str` because some of the tokens can be macros and type `str`  detokenize them.

I took a look at the `char` functions, but coudn't find any to help. Did I miss something useful?

Comment: if you use pdftex (rather than luatex or xetex) then the tokens are always single byte representing (in this case) the UTF-8 stream, you can not have a single token for the characters past 7F so it isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: `\char_to_utfviii_bytes:n` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `pdflatex` the function `\tl_map_inline:nn` will just consider `á` as two bytes. We can check whether the character code is a high byte and act consequently. If the object passed to it is more than one token, like for `{$\beta$}`, we can print it as is.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\processtl}{m}
 {
  \jander_process_tl:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jander_process_tl:n
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    ( % open parenthesis
    \tl_if_single:nTF { ##1 }
     {
      \__jander_process_highbyte:en { `\token_to_str:N ##1 } { ##1 }
     }
     { ##1 }
     ) % close parenthesis
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__jander_process_highbyte:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1>127 } { 0x\int_to_Hex:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jander_process_highbyte:nn { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

token list: \processtl{abc{$\beta$}}

token list with á and ç: \processtl{ábç{$\beta$}}

\end{document}
```

What happens? When `á` is found, it's actually `0xC3` followed by `0xA1`. In either case it's a sequence of single tokens, as far as `pdftex` is concerned. So we can compute its character code (but we need to make it an “other character”, because it might be active) and pass it to another function that checks whether it's a high byte.

[image]

A modification for taking into account that a single token might be a control sequence.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\processtl}{m}
 {
  \sys_if_engine_pdftex:TF
   {
    \jander_process_tl_onebyte:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    \jander_process_tl_unicode:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jander_process_tl_onebyte:n
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    ( % open parenthesis
    \bool_lazy_or:nnTF { ! \tl_if_single_p:n { ##1 } } { \token_if_cs_p:N ##1 }
     {
      ##1
     }
     {
      \__jander_process_highbyte:en { `\token_to_str:N ##1 } { ##1 }
     }
     ) % close parenthesis
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__jander_process_highbyte:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1>127 } { 0x\int_to_Hex:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jander_process_highbyte:nn { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

token list: \processtl{abc{$\beta$}}

token list with á and ç: \processtl{ábç{$\beta$}\LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The trick to save coding is to use `\bool_lazy_or:nnTF`; the first condition reads “not a single token” and the second “a control sequence”. Since we use lazy evaluation, when the first condition is true (so we don't have a single token) the second is not evaluated.

[image]

Comment: That's very interesting. I should have thought about converting a single token to string! Great answer!

Comment: Is it possible to check if a token is a macro (e.g. `\something`). For example, if I `\def\myalpha{$\alpha$}` and try `\processtl{abc{$\beta$}\myalpha}` it fails with "Undefined control sequence. ...n list: \processtl{abc{$\beta$}{\myalpha}}". I believe this happens because `\myalpha` is a single token and the code tries to get it's hex value.

Comment: Maybe with `\cs_if_exist_p:N`?

Comment: @Jander No, it's `\token_if_cs:NTF`, but we can do better and use “lazy or evaluation“. See update.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want something like this (it could print in hex with a bit more effort)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\processtl}[1]{{
\def\UTFviii@two@octets##1{\number\expandafter`\string##1}
\def\UTFviii@invalid@err##1{\number\expandafter`\string##1}
    \tl_map_inline:nn {#1} { (##1) } %% Here: check one byte!
}}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
token list: \processtl{abc{$\beta$}}

 token list with á and ç: \processtl{ábç{$\beta$}}\par  % FAILS
\end{document}
```

Comment: A very compact answer! I have to  take a closer look at it since I just don't get it. Where can I find more information related to `\UTFviii@two@octets`?

Comment: it's the handling of UTF-8 in inputenc (so pre-loaded into the format in current releases) see `texdoc utf8ienc.pdf`  which should show you utf8ienc.pdf from latex base distribution. @Jander  Of course for the full range you should have (identical) lines for `\UTFviii@three@octets`  and `\UTFviii@four@octets`